# How to use another command after `norm` in `:global`?

Tags: vim

For example, I have some HTML `<p>` with several sentences and want to **extract the content** and put each sentence **in its own line**. I want this **for all paragraphs** in **one command run**.
So from:

```html
<p>Hello. This is Alan. I am a wookie.</p>

<p>Hello. This is Bob. I am an ewok.</p>
```

I want to get:

```
Hello.
This is Alan.
I am a wookie.

Hello.
This is Bob.
I am a ewok.
```

I can extract all `<p>` contents by running `:g/<p>/norm ditVp`.
I can also place my cursor in such extracted paragraph and run `:s/\.\s\?/.\r/g` to split them all. How can I merge this in one command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when we want to have multiple commands in one line then we use `|`.
But you are performing `:g` and then within it `:norm`. As we read in `:h :bar` both of them treat `|` as their argument. In such situation we use `:execute`.
Since we want for the `:s` to be part of `:g`, then we will enclose `:norm` in `:exec` like so:

```
:g/<p>/exec "norm! ditVp" | s/\.\s\?/.\r/g
```